# Dynamically creating a form of checkboxes from nested JSON with ReactiveForms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a data structure which consists of a parent category such as music. its title is defines in the object under `hobbies[0].parent.title` I want to have a ngFor which outputs this title out (I have no issues here), then under that there will be another nested ngFor dealing with the sub-genres which is under the `hobbies[0].children[i]` as an array - I would like to output these as checkboxes which is again no problem but the issue arises when I try to make them a reactive form, my basic need is to validate that at least 1 or 2 have been checked and to get the info of the checked item, with ReactiveForms I have a good idea how to achieve this without a nested json struct, its really throwing me off

I have tried a ton of different approaches in these articles but I cant seem to get it to work, any help much appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-3-levels

https://medium.com/hashtaagco/3-levels-of-nested-form-arrays-including-reactive-validations-we-decided-to-go-inception-mode-on-4fffe667fb2a

https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-4-forms-validation

https://jenniferwadella.com/blog/managing-dynamic-and-nested-forms-angular

Ive been playing around with this for a few hours by my html has stayed the same

```
  <form [formGroup]="form"  action="">
    <label *ngFor="let parent of fetchInterests; let i = index">
      <div  *ngFor="let item of parent.children; let i = index">
        <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>  {{  item.title }} {{  item.selected }}
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
```

my json demo data is  below

```
var hobbies = [{
            "parent": {
                "parentId": "dMGkZuB8JV",
                "title": "Music",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg"
            },
            "children": [{
                "title": "Jazz",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }, {
                "title": "Rock",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }, {
                "title": "Classical",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }, {
                "title": "Soul",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }]
        }, {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": "19h2yOfZaq",
                "title": "computers and systems",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/it/placeholder.jpg"
            },
            "children": [{
                "title": "data processing",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/it/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }]
        }, {
            "parent": {
                "parentId": "m2zQkAgOog",
                "title": "African planes",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/outdoors/placeholder.jpg"
            },
            "children": [{
                "title": "camping",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/outdoors/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }, {
                "title": "swimming",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/outdoors/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }, {
                "title": "hunting",
                "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/outdoors/placeholder.jpg",
                "about": "",
                "selected": false
            }]
        }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kravitz, first think about what do you want to change. You can planning change only selected, or all the object.

I supouse you want to change only the "check", so you need a formArray of formArrays

```
  hobbiesForm: FormArray
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hobbiesForm = new FormArray(this.hobbies.map(x => new FormArray([], this.customValidator())))

    //this give so formArray as hobbies you get
    this.hobbies.forEach((x, index) => {  //for each hobiee
        const array=this.hobbiesForm.at(index) as FormArray
        x.children.forEach(c=>{
          array.push(new FormControl(c.selected))
        })
      })
  }
```

It's a few complex manage a formArray of FormArrays, but you only need take account that when we make `*ngFor="let control of formArray.controls"`, "control" is the element in the array. So in `hobbiesForm.controls` will be a FormArray and inside the formArray will be a control.

Well, better in code

```
<form [formGroup]="hobbiesForm" (submit)="submit(hobbiesForm)">
  <!--array is the inner FormArray--->
  <div *ngFor="let array of hobbiesForm.controls;let i=index">
    <b>{{hobbies[i].parent.title}}:</b>
    <!--control is the inner control of the array-->
    <div *ngFor="let control of array.controls;let j=index">
    <label>{{hobbies[i].children[j].title}}</label>
    <input  type="checkbox" [formControl]="control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Well, in submit we perhafs want to change the "hobbies" object, remember that we only has in value some like `[[true,false,false,true],[false],[true,false,false]]`

```
submit(form)
  {
    if (form.valid)
    {
      form.value.forEach((x,i)=>
      {
         x.forEach((c,j)=>{
            this.hobbies[i].children[j].selected=c;
         })
      })
      console.log(this.hobbies)
    }
  }
```

A customValidator can be like

```
customValidator() {
    return (formArray: FormArray) => {
      return formArray.value.filter(x=>x).length>0?null:{error:"at leat one"}
    }
  }
```

If is over all the form

```
customValidatorOverAll(min)
  {
    return (formArray: FormArray) => {
      let count=0;

      formArray.value.forEach(x=>{
         count+=x?x.filter(c=>c).length:0;
      })
      return count>=min?null:{error:"At least select "+min}
    }
  }
```

you can see it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxjadq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** well, this question is about ion-select. A ion-select multiple return an array with the values, so the things are very different. We are goin to obtain some like
`[["Jazz","Rock"]["dat aprocessing"],["camping"]]`

Thats an array of array but, we need an array of FormControls only. yes a FormControl can store any thing even an array. So

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hobbiesForm = new FormArray(
      this.hobbies.map(x => new FormControl('', this.customValidator())))
  }
```

And our .html some like

```
<form [formGroup]="hobbiesForm" (submit)="submit(hobbiesForm)">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let control of hobbiesForm.controls;let i=index">
        <ion-label>{{hobbies[i].parent.title}}:</ion-label>

        <ion-select [formControl]="control" multiple="true" cancelText="cancel" okText="ok">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let hobbiee of hobbies[i].children; let i = index" 
               [value]="hobbiee.title" selected="false">{{hobbiee.title}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Again we iterate over `hobbiesForm.controls`. But in this case, the select gives us an array.

Well, I put a customValidator. If we want that at least was select one it's only that our customValidator was like

```
customValidator() {
    return (formControl: FormControl) => {
      return formControl.value && formControl.value.length>0?null:{error:"At least select one"}
    }
  }
```

If we want a customValidator over All the form, we can use some like

```
customValidatorOverAll(min)
  {
    return (formArray: FormArray) => {
      let count=0;
      formArray.value.forEach(x=>{
         count+=x.length;
      })
      return count>=min?null:{error:"At least select "+min}
    }
  }
```

And when we create the formArray

```
this.hobbiesForm = new FormArray(this.hobbies.map(x => new FormControl(''))
,this.customValidatorOverAll(2))
```

The [ion-select stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-multiple-jan8x5?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

NOTE: See that we iterate over `formArray.controls`, not over hobbies object, and use two index i,j and hobbies object to show the "labels", but this don't belong to the formArray

Comment: Wow this is fantastic!

Comment: K@Kravitz, no, it's not good, I mkae with heck, and you're using ion-select. I supouse multiple. Let me a time to update my answer with ion-select multiple

Comment: Awesome thanks, also how would you go about validating to make sure at least 2/3 are selected

Comment: I updated my answer using ion-select. I don't know what do you want to say "at leas 2/3 are selected" form all or at least one on each option? If you want that was select 2/3 of all, you need that the validator was over all the form

Comment: Also its not an ion select :) its just ion-input checkboxes but awesome to have that example too... Im trying to use this min validator with the checkboxes but it doesnt work, the form stays invalid

Comment: update answer and the first stackblitz (you need create a customValidator). It's only a function that return null or an object

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting children as a separate array you can mention inside parent.

```
var hobbies = [{
        "parent": {
            "parentId": "dMGkZuB8JV",
            "title": "Music",
            "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg"
            "children": [{
                 "title": "Jazz",
                 "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
                 "about": "",
                  "selected": false
                  }, {
            "title": "Rock",
            "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
            "about": "",
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "title": "Classical",
            "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
            "about": "",
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "title": "Soul",
            "hero": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/music/placeholder.jpg",
            "about": "",
            "selected": false
        }]

        }

    }
```

Comment: How do I create the form controls

Comment: Can you please upload your code in stackblitz and share the link